# C# Scraping Data from Bloomberg article

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping

I'm using a console application to get the HTML data from a Bloomberg article. If I run it in Postman it pulls it all back without issue. I've tried a few different ways (RestSharp, Net.Http), but always get an OK response with the content being "Terms of service violation, click check box if you're not a Robot".

```
    public static void GetUrlHtmlData(string urlRequest)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2018-08-19/elon-musk-says-changing-his-way-of-working-is-not-an-option").Result)
            {
                using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                {
                    string result = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    Console.WriteLine(result);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm assuming this is the intended response for this, but wanted to see if anyone has been able to get around this. I just want the article HTML to parse for meta data and am unable to get around this. I know it's not due to volume or multiple requests. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The server answers as usual. You need to add `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` and you need to a `User-Agent` header: `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0");` otherwise you'll get a *Violation of security terms* message. If you need some help setting this up, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for giving the answer without setting it up and letting me try. That worked, and it's working now. Thanks so much! Also, it won't let me vote or accept as the answer but thank you!

Comment: Was just giving this a try but still get the Terms of Violation message... Anything wrong or changed? https://dotnetfiddle.net/dbbUfF

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nslRtP I ended up having to use HttpClientHandler, automatic compression, gzip to get around it. It worked a few times then went back to Violation terms probably due to multiple requests from the same IP. The fiddle errors out but throw it into a .net core console app and breakpoint on the result and you'll see the response html.